# Recursion tracing within for loop

Tags: php, recursion

I trying to understand function recursion but I've got stuck on a snippet that I have. I fully understand the factorial example where you call over and over until the number match 1 but here the problem is, what gets executed first? The foreach loop or the recursive call?

Here is the snippet:

For example, given the initial string 'abc' which would be the value for the first time the foreach loop gets executed when it is called ( permute($str) as $permutation )?

```
function permute($str)
{
    if (strlen($str) < 2) 
    {
        return array($str);
    }

    $permutations = array();

    $tail = substr($str, 1);

    foreach (permute($tail) as $permutation) 
    {
        $length = strlen($permutation);

        for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) 
        {
           $permutations[] = substr($permutation, 0, $i) . $str[0] . substr($permutation, $i);
        }
    }

    /* Return the result */
    return $permutations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a kind of meaningless piece of code.

The function `permute` always returns an empty array because `$permutations` value which the function returns has never been changed (from initial `array()` value) since initialization.

The function call itself interatively passing itself the decreasuing tail of string until the tail will consist of just 2 characters. Then it echoes these characters in normal and reverse order. That is all

So running `permute('abc')` you will just see `bccb` and recieve `array()` as function result.

My variant (works as well with array or string input)

```
function permute($arg) {
    $array = is_string($arg) ? str_split($arg) : $arg;
    if(1 === count($array))
        return array(array_shift($array));
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $item)
        foreach(permute(array_diff_key($array, array($key => $item))) as $p)
            $result[] = $item . $p;
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look around for some tips on how to do recursion properly. The idea is to incrementally reduce a problem to the trivial case. Don't try to visualise the entire call hierarchy.

You don't seem to know how to approach the problem. The easiest way to implement a recursive algorithm is normally with two functions: one recursive and a helper which calls it once to start the ball rolling. Have a look at this:

```
function permute($string) {
    $permutations = array();
    permuteHelper('', $string, $permutations);
    return $permutations;
}

function permuteHelper($prefix, $string, array &$store) {
    $length = strlen($string);
    if($length === 0) {
        $store[] = $prefix;
    }
    else {
        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            permuteHelper($prefix . $string[$i], substr($string, 0, $i) . substr($string, $i + 1), $store);
        }
    }
}
```

Credit: adapted from [this implementation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/Permutations.java.html) in Java.